# Pulling image from ECR via docker-py

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dockerpy, aws-ecr

I have a script that retrieves a login for ECR, authenticates a DockerClient instance with the login credentials (reauth set to True), and then attempts to pull a nominated container image.

The code seems to work perfectly when running on my local machine interacting with docker daemon on an EC2 instance, but when running from the EC2 instance I am constantly getting

`404 Client Error: Not Found ("repository XXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/autohld-runner not found: does not exist or no pull access")`

The same repo is being used for both executing the code locally and remotely on the EC2 instance.  I have tried setting the access to the image within ECR to allow pull for both everyone and my AWS ID.  I have granted the role assigned to the EC2 instance Full Admin access also.  All with no joy.

If I perform the same tasks on the EC2 instance via command line with the exact same repo URI (copied from the error), it works with no issue.

Is there something I am missing within docker-py ?

```
url = "tcp://127.0.0.1:2375"
dockerd = docker.DockerClient(base_url=url, version='auto')
dockerd.login(username=ecr.username, password=ecr.password, email='none', registry=ecr.registry, reauth=True)
dockerd.images.pull(ecr.get_repo(instance.tags['Container']), tag='latest')
```

`get_repo` returns the full URI as reported in the error message, the Container element is the name 'autohld-runner'

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that if the registry has been accessed via the cli then an auth token or something is set and docker remembers this allowing subsequent calls to work.  However in this case the instance is starting up completely fresh and using the login method within docker-py.

This doesn't seem to pass the credentials on to the pull, I have found that using the `auth_config` named argument and passing in a dictionary of auth parameters works.

```
auth_creds = {'username': ecr.username, 'password': ecr.password}
dockerd.images.pull(ecr.get_repo(instance.tags['Container']), tag='latest', auth_config=auth_creds)
```

HTH